# Apply Material UI's TouchRipple Component to custom elements/components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I have a list in my material-ui application that has columns and (icon) buttons.

When an item in the list is clicked I want to have the ripple affect from Material Design.

Material UI's lists do come with the ripple effect when clicked, unfortunately because I'm using a custom list (because I need to have multiple columns and a lot of other customizations) I don't have the the ripple effect (I'm simply using divs to create my list).

I know that Material UI has a component TouchRipple, which is used in all components that have a ripple effect (you can find it in the `internal` directory) I've tried to wrap my custom list items into a TouchRipple component, but unfortunately the animation shows at the top of the page without any relation to the position and size of the actual list item, basically it doesn't work as it should.

My question is, can i, and if yes how do I use the TouchRipple component on my custom components to add the ripple effect to them?

Comment: TouchRipple is not today available in the internal directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work.

Simply adding the style `transform: translate(0px, 0px);` to the parent div generated by the TouchRipple made the ripple at the correct position and size.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by wrapping your custom components with a `<ButtonBase>` component. See the "complex buttons" section in the [ButtonBase API page](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/) for an example.